# Losing characters in long HTTP Responses in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, encoding, utf-8

We have an ASP.NET MVC site running on IIS 8.

When our client's site is in Cyrillic, we often see rhombus with question marks in some spots where normal characters should be.

For example, here is how it looks rendered in browser:
[image]

I've enable Filed Requests Traicing for 200 status code responses in IIS, and was able to see when is traced as a part of buffer sent from IIS down to the clients. The following link shows the text I see in the xml log file for this particular paragraph:

http://notepad.cc/blubliagi91

This is what actual html in the browser looks like:
http://notepad.cc/hiccehe19

Another thing I've noticed, is that when I restart site, first time the page is requested, it is rhombus free. Every consequent requests is crippled.

Please look at the provided text files and let me know where to look for from here.

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**
I've decoded the string for that

that is traced to actual readable Cyrillic and I see that rhombus are already there. So whatever it is breaking the encoding sequence, it happens before IIS ships out the response stream.

**UPDATE 2**

I've saved the initial, clean response that renders without rhombus in browsers to trace log and found that initial buffer is different. The second buffer entry starts exactly where rhombus would appear in every consequent responses.
This is how second buffer entry starts:
http://notepad.cc/zbewuqu71

So rhombus occur every response after first one. On first one, the place of split of buffer would mark the place of rhombus occurrence in each next response.

Comment: How are you generating this text? ASP.NET uses MVC and UTF-8 by default and shouldn't have any issues *unless* the encoding was changed by hand, or the text is HTML or URL encoded when it doesn't have to. The links you posted contain URL encoded text.

Comment: The text in question is checked in MVC pipeline. It is in the database without rhombuses. It travels through application logic in a correct form. It is rendered via Razor into a correctly looking html. And the only catch I have is that when IIS will server the response, those characters that will be on the edge of the buffer, will appear with rhombuses in every consequent response.

Comment: Please post the code. Your link shows text that has already been encoded by someone. Note that some MVC helpers do encode text while [Html.Raw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) doesn't - that's your code though. The `?` is a clear sign that there was another conversion, probably between one ASCII codepage to another (is the column varchar or nvarchar?). `?` is the replacement character when OLEDB or Win32 can't convert a character from one codepage to another

Comment: Html.Raw does indeed render the parts in question in the Razor View. I just don't know which part of code to paste, since the pipeline through wich the text goes is rather long.